# Send multiple UDP packets in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, client-server, structure, video-capture

I am trying to create a Client-Server application to send/receive video frame over UDP in python 2.7. I am using cv2 to capture the video frame from the webcam and break it down into packets to send it over UDP, as sending the complete image results in error for maximum transfer buffer size.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import socket
import sys
import pickle
import struct
import time

pkSZ = 5000
flag = False
counter = 0

class img_data():
    def __init__ (self):
        pkid = 0
        start = False
        data = ""
        end = False
        pk_size = 0
        act_sz = 0

def StartStreamSending():
    UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
    UDP_PORT = 8013
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    clientsocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_SNDBUF, pkSZ*2)
    objImg = img_data()

    while True:
        ret,frame = cap.read()

        data = np.array(frame)
        dataToSend = pickle.dumps(data)
        size = sys.getsizeof(dataToSend)

        objImg.act_sz = len(dataToSend)

        print "Actual Size : " + str(objImg.act_sz)

        if( len(dataToSend) > pkSZ ):

            flag = True
            counter = 1
            sz_send = 0

            while (flag == True):

                TruncData = (dataToSend[:pkSZ])

                objImg.pkid = counter
                objImg.start = True
                objImg.data = TruncData
                objImg.end = False
                objImg.pk_size = len(TruncData)

                counter += 1

                # Send data
                clientsocket.sendto(objImg, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

                sz_send = sz_send + objImg.size

                if( sz_send < (len(dataToSend) - sz_send ) ):
                    flag = True

                elif( sz_send >= len(dataToSend) ):
                    flag = False

                    objImg.pkid += counter
                    objImg.start = False
                    objImg.data = TruncData
                    objImg.end = True
                    objImg.pk_size = len(TruncData)

                    # Send data
                    clientsocket.sendto(objImg, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

                    break

        elif( len(dataToSend) < pkSZ ):
            flag = False

            objImg.pkid += counter
            objImg.start = False
            objImg.data = TruncData
            objImg.end = True
            objImg.pk_size = len(TruncData)

            # Send data
            clientsocket.sendto(objImg, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

        time.sleep(5)

StartStreamSending()
```

After I included the logic to truncate the data and send it, it is working but if I try to send the structure as a packet on UDP, I get an error stating the data to be sent needs to be string and not an instance.

Kindly provide a fix or alternate way to transfer video in python.